# change wallpaper via iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, preview, wallpaper, photos

Does apple allows me to change the wallpaper of the iphone from my application?

Answer (score 3):

The public iOS 4.0 API so far does not allow changing any of the iPhone wallpapers programmatically.  Undocumented APIs are not supported by Apple, so no, I don't think they would allow it.

However, technically it should be possible to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, no public APIs for it even with the latest SDK. You need to ask the user to save your image as a wallpaper manually.