# iPhone - change the wallpaper?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, wallpaper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change wallpaper via iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057885/change-wallpaper-via-iphone-app)

How can I change the wallpaper on iPhone using Cocoa Touch/Objective-C ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Apple doesn't provide any public API. You can find answers to this question in other posts like mentioned in the above comment.

[change wallpaper via iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057885/change-wallpaper-via-iphone-app)

[How to change the system wallpaper/background of an iOS device with Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397710/how-to-change-the-system-wallpaper-background-of-an-ios-device-with-objective-c)

[Setting The Wallpaper On An IPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612160/setting-the-wallpaper-on-an-ipad)

[How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649529/how-to-change-wallpaper-in-ipad-programmatically)